# Any good site for learning jQuery with live examples (typing the code on screen and seeing the effects live)

Tags: jquery

I have to teach a colleague jQuery and I think this would be a fun and quick way to learn it. I have seen brief tutorials and examples out there that use this technique: you have some content on the page, and a textarea to write and run your code to manipulate the rest of the page.

I was wondering if there is a whole site or course that uses this method. There must be one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what you want - but it costs $45 -

http://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-air-first-flight

Answer (score 3):

www.jsfiddle.net is a very good place to do things like this.

At jsfiddle.net you can type in html, CSS, javascript, import external libraries, etc and then see it all come to life upon clicking the run button. You can even save your examples and share them via URLs.

Also, as far as teaching jQuery via tutorials I really haven't run across any spectacular jQuery tutorials. If your friend doesn't have a good background in HTML DOM elements and Javascript then I would say the best way to teach would be by example (which is what it appears you are trying to do).